# Typescript sourcemaps not displayed in Ionic 2 on an Android device

Tags: android, google-chrome, typescript, ionic2, source-maps

I face a weird Ionic2 behaviour. 
When i deploy my app to a simulator, i can see the .ts file sourceMap in the chrome inspect debugger.

On both case, i use :

```
ionic run android
```

[image]

On the other side, when i deploy my apk on a real device, the tab "Sources" is completely different with an other groups of directories and, with no reference to my .ts files.

[image]

**My environment is:**

- OS X 10.11
- Ionic 2 2.0.0-beta.35
- cordova 6.3.0

**The project has been initially generated by:**

```
ionic start biblio tutorial --v2
```

**ionic.config.json**

```
{
  "name": "biblio",
  "app_id": "",
  "v2": true,
  "typescript": true
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "filesGlob": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "!node_modules/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/global",
    "typings/global.d.ts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

For me the problem was that when you're remote debugging on an android device, Chrome debugger cannot access the source map file on the device. The solution/fix is to include the source map inline. To do this I:

added the below to package.json in the root project directory

```
"config": {
"ionic_bundler": "webpack",
"ionic_source_map_type": "#inline-source-map"
},
```

This is to make the webpack to add source maps inline changed tsconfig.js line

```
"sourceMap": true,
```

to

```
"sourceMap": false
```

This is to disable typescript to create source map file since this is done by webpack.

After this change everything seems to be working fine. Note that this applies to ionic 2 RC_04

Comment: if u change "sourceMap": false it gives error somthing like this

Comment: [18:05:00]  ionic-app-script task: "build" 
[18:05:00]  Error: The "tsconfig.json" file must have compilerOptions.sourceMap set to true. For more information please 
            see the default Ionic project tsconfig.json file here: 
            https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/blob/master/tsconfig.json